# ner::ERR_CACHE_MISS Android 4.4 WebView

Tags: android, caching, webview

I'm trying to make a simple web app that loads a website into a webview.

This is the code:

```
public class Webviewser extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);

    String url = "http://google.com";
    WebView view = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.loadUrl(url);
}
}
```

I have read in other thread that the solution is  to add the INTERNET permission inside the ANDROID MANIFEST. But as you can see I have already added it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Webviewser"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Really nobody can help me??

Comment: I don't actually see the permission in your manifest. Have you pasted the contents of your manifest file correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to sostitute the code with this:

```
WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings faller = view.getSettings();
   faller.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   view.loadUrl("http://google.com");
 view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```